# Logs in Play framework 2.5

Tags: scala, playframework

I’ve upgraded my play framework (Scala) version from **2.2 to 2.5**.

Before, when I was deploying in my preprod environment using the "start-stop-daemon" linux command I was able to see the logs in target/universal/stage/logs/ but now can’t find this folder anymore and wondering where I can find it now.

For information my logger conf in the application.conf is set on « DEBUG »

Comment: please share your logback.xml from your config directory (in case you are using logback)

Answer (score 0):

Play 2.5's logging configuration is different than 2.2  :(

Review the logback.xml approach here:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsLogger